# UITextField - Scroll down when return

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, swift4

I have multiple text fields on a view controller, and have implemented the textFieldShouldReturn function so that when I hit return, it goes to the next text field. However, right now the screen stays the same, so the active text field is covered up by the keyboard.

How can I make it so that the screen scrolls down and I can see the active text field?

Relevant code:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let nextTextFieldTag = textField.tag + 1
        let nextTextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTextFieldTag)

        if nextTextField != nil {
            nextTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return false
    }
```

Comment: add your tried code always

Comment: your code is fine and correct ,  it goes to the next text field -- it works or not, your VC embed in scrollview or else

Comment: @Anbu.karthik yes, but I'm not sure how to make it so I can see the next textfield since the keyboard covers it up

Comment: your textfield is embed in scrollview or tableview or else (directly attached in VC)

Comment: @Anbu.karthik right now I have a custom view that's being set as the VC view. Is it possible to just add the custom view to a scrollView in the VC?

Comment: If you are using the tableview this might be helpful to you.         UITextfield *t1 = // the textfield to which you are moving;
        
        CGPoint point = [t1 convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:TableV];
        NSIndexPath *indP = [TableV indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

Comment: @user3628240 - i updated answer check once

Comment: use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) Don't spend more time on such small issues...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using IQKeyboardManager (https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

All your need to do is add the `IQKeyboardManager` to your Pod, install it and add the initially code. That's all

Copy from https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager
Add to your pod file

```
`pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'`
```

In `AppDelegate.swift`, just `import IQKeyboardManagerSwift` framework and enable IQKeyboardManager.

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

      return true
    }
}
```

If you want to make it yourself.

1. In your  `textFieldShouldReturn`, get the frame of the active textfield
2. New view.frame.y -= activeTextField.frame.y + space
3. Change view.frame.y

Or you can add all your textfield to the scrollview and just simple change scrollview.contentOffset.y

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to scroll in UIScrollView:

- `scrollView.setContentOffset(textField.frame.origin, animated:
  true)`.
- `scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(textField.frame, animated:
  true)`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming all your text fields on scroll view `scrollView`. Now you want next textfield `nextTextField` to scroll up. In that case -

In your `if` condition -

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x : 0, y : nextTextField.frame.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your `viewDidLoad()` like this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

And use these functions to show `UITextField` from when keyboard is shown

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print(keyboardSize.height)
        if view.frame.origin.y >= 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue{
        print(keyboardSize.height)
        if view.frame.origin.y < 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you start to use an textfield and you want to move your ScrollView.

   ```
    weak var activeField:[UITextField]!       
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField 
        if let scroll = scrollVC
            {
                scroll.keyboardDismissMode = 
                UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.interactive
                scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 
                self.activeField.frame.origin.y - 64), animated: true)
            }
           }
   ```
2. When you dismiss your keyboard, use a return or use .becomeFirstResponder()

   ```
   func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   if let scroll = scrollVC{
       scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: activeField == 
       textField ? 0 : textField.frame.origin.y), animated: true)
   }
   ```
3. An example how i use first responders when I have 2 or more TextFields:
   You should add all your UITextFields in Array.

   ```
     @objc func dismissKeyboard(){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
     }

     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       switch activeField {            
       case arrTextFields[0]:
           arrTextFields[1].becomeFirstResponder()
       case arrTextFields[1]:
           arrTextFields[2].becomeFirstResponder()
       default:
           dismissKeyboard()
       }
       return true
   }
   ```